# How do I decrypt in PHP?

Tags: java, php

I have AES Decryption with Java code but I want to decrypt with PHP code. Can you help me out?

```
//provided key
byte[] keyBinary = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("r/RloSflFkLj3Pq2gFmdBQ==");
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(keyBinary, "AES");

// encrypted msisdn
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("IKWpOq9rhTAz/K1ZR0znPA==");

// iv
byte[] iv = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("yzXzUhr3OAt1A47g7zmYxw==");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv)); String msisdn = new 
String(cipher.doFinal(bytes), "UTF-8");
```

I have tried below PHP code but no getting result

```
$key = hex2bin('X9Rgj55s7txnPAVJDlxTuA==');
$iv = hex2bin('yzXzUhr3OAt1A47g7zmYxw==');

$output = openssl_decrypt('IKWpOq9rhTAz/K1ZR0znPA==', 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 
OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in PHP to get a result?. Kindly edit your question and post the PHP-code you are struggling with, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything in PHP yet ? Have you looked at [php's openssl_decrypt function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) ? Read some of the user notes at the bottom of the page as well, they provide some useful tips.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Sorry, I forgot to add my code. I have updated my code what I tried.

Comment: @NoahBoegli I have updated my code what I tried.

Comment: The function `hex2bin` does not decode base64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

All data (ciphertext, key and iv) are encoded in Base64 (and not in hex string format) so you need to decode them to get the correct values.

Second: the key is (when decoded) a 16 byte long key so on Java side
the encryption/decryption runs with AES "128" - algorithm; in PHP you are specifying the "AES 256" algo that has to fail.

Here is a short program that decrypts the data to "**1234567**".

code:

```
<?php
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64604909/how-do-i-decrypt-in-php
$ciphertextBase64 = "IKWpOq9rhTAz/K1ZR0znPA==";
$keyBase64 = "r/RloSflFkLj3Pq2gFmdBQ==";
$ivBase64 = "yzXzUhr3OAt1A47g7zmYxw==";

$ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertextBase64);
$key = base64_decode($keyBase64);
$iv = base64_decode($ivBase64);

$decryptedtext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
echo 'decryptedtext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;
?>
```